# Why Copying CMD commands from OneNote to CMD adds folder name starts with "."?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, microsoft-onenote

When I copy CMD command within OneNote Table and pasted into Command Prompt in Windows 7. It automatically adds first folder within current directory starts with ".".

This is the command in OneNote:

[image]

Once I copy and paste into Command-prompt, it turns to this:

```
 dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator .\.vscontroller -name "AddUser" -outDir Controllers
```

I don't why. Can anyone help me solve this issue?

Comment: When pasted in notepad reveals nothing, but it happens in CMD only

Answer (score 1):

It looks like spaces were causing issue. What I did copied table from OneNote to Microsoft Word then remove all spaces and pasted back to the terminal solved the issue of automatically adding a folder name starts with "." e.g. .android